# ANTLR v4 runtime Java packages not recognized

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to run ANTLR v4 with Java. I am trying to run the below file, Hello.java:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}
```

with the following script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
ANTLR_LIB="antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar"

# Making an empty out directory
touch out
rm -r out
mkdir out

# Generating code
java -jar ${ANTLR_LIB} -no-listener -visitor Expr.g4 -o out/


# Adding in our own code
cp *.java out/

# Compiling everything together
javac -classpath ".;[MY FILE PATH]\antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar" -cp .:out:${ANTLR_LIB} out/Hello.java

# Showing the parse tree
# java -cp .:out:${ANTLR_LIB} org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Expr prog -gui $1

# Run the calculator
# java -classpath .:out/:${ANTLR_LIB} Calc $1
```

I have set my CLASSPATH to include antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar, but when I try to run the script, I run into this error:

[image]

I am unsure how to resolve this error.

Comment: Your javac command has `-cp` and `-classpath` which is odd (I don't know what the result of doing that is). Where exactly is `antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar`?

Comment: @tgdavies antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar and Hello.java are stored in the same directory:

$ dir Hello.java antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar
Hello.java  antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you're using both `-classpath` and `-cp`: don't. Just use one of them.

Compiling all Java source files inside `./out` (of which some are dependent on the ANTLR runtime) can be done as follows:

#### Linux & Mac OS

```
javac -cp .:out:antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar out/*.java
```

#### Windows

```
javac -cp .;out;antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar out\*.java
```